# Linux (Ubuntu) use Windows shared drive for www folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, network-share, file-sharing

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 server running Hyper-V which runs a Ubuntu.

The Windows server has other HD for files (which are then made Windows Shared drives for the network).

I'd like to use one of those drives for the www folder of Ubuntu, i.e. allowing files to be stored on the second hard drive (which has RAID set up and can be accessed by the other computers on the network - which are running Windows).

I know that Windows shared folders can be accessed via Linux, however, I cannot find information (whether this is even possible) to use such a drive for the www folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need [cifs-utils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=cifs-utils) and an entry in `/etc/fstab`. Implementation will vary depending how/if you intend to authenticate to the `cifs://` share.

I'm also uncertain if this is actually a good idea, but you're closer to the details of this than I.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for and it's all working now :)